# Registering generic interface and implementation in a nested container in stucturemap

Tags: c#, generics, structuremap

After and upgrade from StructureMap 2.6.4 to StructureMap 3.1.6 the registration for our generic interfaces that we have in our nested containers stopped working and I can't find the reason why they doesn't work anymore.

This is the error I'm getting

> StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException : No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'ITest<ExtendClass>'

Here is a sample that demonstrate the problem:

```
public class StructureMapContainerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void GlobalContainer()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Configure(x => x.For(typeof(ITest<>)).Use(typeof(Test<>)));

        var impl = container.GetInstance<ITest<ExtendClass>>();

        Debug.WriteLine(impl.Temp()); //Works
    }

    [Test]
    public void NestedContainer()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        var nestedContainer = container.GetNestedContainer();

        nestedContainer.Configure(x => x.For(typeof(ITest<>)).Use(typeof(Test<>)));

        var impl = nestedContainer.GetInstance<ITest<ExtendClass>>();

        Debug.WriteLine(impl.Temp()); //Doesn't work
    }
}

public interface ITest<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    string Temp();
}

public class Test<T> : ITest<T> where T : ExtendClass
{
    public string Temp()
    {
        return "OK: " + typeof(T);
    }
}

public class BaseClass { }

public class ExtendClass : BaseClass { }
```

Both of the tests above works in StructureMap 2.6.4 but in 3.1.6 the second test that uses a nested container doesn't work anymore.

Does anybody know if this is a feature that has been removed or I'm simply using it wrong and in that case can help me out some? :)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you can register neither generic types nor decorators within StructureMap's nested containers.

The way we worked around this was to split the registry into 2 registries, one containing the generics and decorators being registered into the parent container and the other with non-generic interfaces registered into the nested container.  Unfortunately this is not always easy to do when building an extensible system.

Here's Jeremy's response to Tobias from [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/structuremap-users/8B-p8fkBllQ) for anyone else interested.

> The nested container architecture was a complete rewrite for 3.0. To be honest, I think the fact that that worked on 2.6.* is just a happy accident.
>
> Right now, that type of registration on a nested container is not supported...
>
> Jeremy D. Miller